# The menu at the right side of the navbar is hiding whenever i try to resize my browser window width greater than 600 pixels

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my HTML Code and i am trying to make a responsive navbar which is working fine if i resize it to mobile view but whenever i click the menu icon in mobile view and try to hide my right menu and resize it to desktop format the menu at the right side always hides but i dont want that the menu should hide whenever i try to resize it to desktop format please somebody help me out to solve this problem. I am using jquery below in this html code to slide the menu up and down is there any easy way to do that using css.

Here is my css code

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li:hover {
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.page-block {
    height: 30%;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 6% 10%;
    background-color: #d7d7d7;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10% auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

nav {
    display: block;
    height:  100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-brand {
    color: darkgrey;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.active {
    background-color: orange;
    color: #fff;
}

.right-menu-toggle {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid darkgrey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 30px;
    color: darkgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-right {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 6px;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.menu-right ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-right ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu-right ul li a{
    padding: 8px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-right ul li a:hover {
    background-color: darkgrey;
    color: white;
}


/* ------- Media query ------- */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .nav-brand {
        display: block;
    }


    .menu-right {
        display: none;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    }

    .menu-right ul li{
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
    }

    .menu-right ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 20px;
    }

    .right-menu-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Here is my html code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" >
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
        <title>Navbar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font_awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo_nav.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-brand">
                <p><a href="#">Navbar Brand</a><p>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-right">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="right-menu-toggle">menu</div>

        </nav>
        <div class="page-block">
            <h1>NAVBAR DEMO</h1>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".right-menu-toggle").click(function(){
                    $(".menu-right").slideToggle(500);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the problem. Does [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/msaw2y1L/) show it?

Comment: I think I see now. If your mobile menu is hidden the desktop menu doesn't appear.

Comment: I suggest you review the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/). You don't need to write your own menu toggler function.

Comment: my navbar is working fine but whenever i try to close the menu items in mobile view by clicking the menu icon at the right side of brand logo the menu items get hidden even in desktop view also instead i want them not to be hidden in desktop view

Comment: I agree with @isherwood. When you are already using a library, why bother about worrying about doing something that already has support in the library.